# Python + TypeError: MarketData.get_kline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kline_type'

Tags: python

I need to extract BTC data from Kucoin. Here is the python code:

```js
import kucoin.client as kc
import pandas as pd

api_key = '***6120**********'
api_secret = '****-0078**************'

client = kc.Market(url='https://api.kucoin.com', key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

symbol = 'BTC-USDT'
interval = '1day'
start_time = '2022-01-01'
end_time = '2022-04-29'
kline_type = 'spot'

klines = client.get_kline(symbol=symbol, interval=interval, startAt=start_time, endAt=end_time, klineType=kline_type)
```

I keep getting  the following error:
TypeError: MarketData.get_kline() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kline_type'

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo:

```
klineType=kline_type
```

should be:

```
kline_type=kline_type
```

Comment: Thanks. That throws a different error:  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kucoin\base_request\base_request.py", line 118, in check_response_data
    raise Exception("{}-{}".format(response_data.status_code, response_data.text))
Exception: 400-{"msg":"Bad Request","code":"400000"}

Comment: @hdsouza this new error means that you sent a web request that does not respect the specified format. I suggest thinking about it, then if you cannot find the solution, ask a new question (each StackOverflow question is about a single error)